# How to add/store coordinate values to a list ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, arraylist, geocoding

I'm trying to save coordinates to a list of some type so that I can store them for future manipulation within the application but I'm not sure how I would go about this. In the onNavigatedTo method of the application I have a GeoCoordinate variable `MyGeoPosition` that I want to store.

Can someone show me how I would achieve this and what type of list to use for this issue?

This is the complete method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLat") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLong") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("pName"))
            {
                var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"]);
                var longtitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLong"]);
                var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longtitude);
                var pushPinName = NavigationContext.QueryString["pName"];

                DrawPushPin(MyGeoPosition,pushPinName);

            }

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<GeoCoordinate> mycoord = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
mycoord.add(MyGeoPosition);
```

But you need to write mycoord as class member, not as automatic variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a list of type

```
var mycoord = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
mycoord.Add(mycoord);
```

Comment: var MyGeoPosition; // MyGeoPosition is object, not type

Comment: Simon's solution is what you need, but depending on the type of application, you'd want `var mycoord = new List<MyGeoPosition>();` outside the event handler, maybe as a property of the application class so you'd have access to it everywhere in the app.

Comment: Please mark as answer if that answers your question

Comment: still error: List<GeoCoordinate> can not be added in a container of type List<GeoCoordinate>. mycoord.Add(mycoord);// this line wont compile. @Simon